# Are there any good wma to mp3 converters?

Tags: windows, conversion, mp3, music, wma

I'm looking for a batch converter to take wma's in a directory and convert them to mp3.  Is there anything out there that will do this?  This will be for windows.

Comment: on what platform?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The free version of [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) will do it. FYI lossy to lossy conversion is a Very Bad Thing (if your .wma's are lossy).

Comment: +1 for pointing out that lossy conversion is a bad thing

Comment: Just a note: The free version can only encode to MP3 for 30 days.

Comment: @Randy - however, it's very simple to replace the lame encoder dll supplied with Media Monkey with one that isn't time limited.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for the tip about replacing the dll.  Got the steps from [here](http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/How_can_I_rip_mp3s_from_CDs_beyond_MM's_free_trial_period%3F) and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 2):

[MediaCoder](http://mediacoder.sourceforge.net/index.htm) will do this, it's free and open source.

Comment: The link in the answer is to an apparently dormant SourceForge page, try this one:
http://www.mediacoderhq.com/

Answer (score 2):

I always find the [Audio Converter Switch](http://www.nch.com.au/switch/) one of the easiest audio converters around.

It downloads necessary codecs on-the-fly and it really converts almost anything.

Even the free or trial version does what it suppose to do and doesn't get in the way in the future, except maybe for a winrar like dialog when it starting up...

[image]

Comment: The free version is unlimited for non-commercial use, commercial use requires the paid Switch Plus version, which also includes additional formats.

Comment: this one works **awesome!** the free version just works! +1!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [dBpoweramp music convertor](http://dbpoweramp.com/dmc.htm).

It has powerful batch convert options, or you might find it simpler to highlight all the input files in the folder, right click and select 'convert to'.

It's not free, but you can download a 21 day free trial from the website.

Answer (score 1):

Try [FormatFactory](http://www.formatoz.com/)

> Format Factory is a multifunctional media converter.
>   Provides functions below:
>   All to MP4/3GP/MPG/AVI/WMV/FLV/SWF.
>   All to MP3/WMA/AMR/OGG/AAC/WAV.
>   All to JPG/BMP/PNG/TIF/ICO/GIF/TGA.
>   Rip DVD to video file , Rip Music CD to audio file.
>   MP4 files support iPod/iPhone/PSP/BlackBerry format.
>   Supports RMVB.
>   
>   Format Factory's Feature:
>   1 support converting all popular video,audio,picture formats to others.
>   2 Repair damaged video and audio file.
>   3 Reducing Multimedia file size.
>   4 Support iphone,ipod multimedia file formats.
>   5 Picture converting supports Zoom,Rotate/Flip,tags.
>   6 DVD Ripper.
>   7 Supports 50 languages

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: looks cheap...oh well.

Comment: Yes, but don't judge a book by its cover. Sits ontop of ffmpeg, mencoder, mplayer

Comment: I was under the impression that FF looks cheap and nasty, but I was pleasantly surprised when it just works.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes can do this too. Just add your WMAs to your iTunes library and it will ask you if you want to convert them to MP3.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to convert common WMA music to MP3, just for example this [audio converter](http://www.aimediasoft.com/audio-converter.html) is enough.
But most WMA music is protected by DRM, so if you want to convert DRM protected WMA to MP3, you need something else, for example [this tool](http://www.diggsofts.com/wma-mp3-converter-daniu.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is a light weight [**MediaCoder Audio edition**](http://mediacoder.sourceforge.net/audio/) perfect for you.