# How can I mass convert from WMA to MP3?

Tags: mp3, wma

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any good wma to mp3 converters?](https://superuser.com/questions/10564/are-there-any-good-wma-to-mp3-converters)

How can I mass convert audio files from WMA to MP3?

Comment: Which OS are you using? It's quite easy in a *nix environment to do this in a terminal.

Comment: Exact duplicate, I think. The answers to that will answer this precisely.

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg is another great option. You can compile it yourself, or grab the Windows binaries from http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/.

Assuming all your wma files are in the same directory, you can run a batch command like

```
FOR %I IN (*.wma) DO <path to ffmpeg.exe> -i "%I" "%I.mp3"
```

in the directory containing all your wma files.

Answer (score 0):

[SoundConverter](http://soundconverter.berlios.de/) can convert from any format that you have GStreamer read plugins for, and to several popular formats.